# Busca Banco de Dados ao Selecionar opções Select

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

bom dia.
Estou com um pequeno problema que não estou conseguindo resolver.
A situação é a seguinte:
Tenho 2 selects (Estado e cidade), gostaria que ao selecionar um estado o sistema fizesse uma busca em meu BD para achar distribuidores daquele estado e ao selecionar a cidade o sistema refinasse ainda mais a busca buscando distribuidores daquele determinado estado + determinada cidade. Isso tudo sem precisar de um botão e sem dar refresh na página.

Tentei adaptar um código que achei na internet, mas não dá nenhum erro, nem aparece algum resultado.

Os estados e cidades são populados automaticamente:

```
<select class="select-onde-comprar" onchange="buscarOndeComprar()" id="estado" name="estado"></select>
<select class="select-onde-comprar" onchange="buscarOndeComprar()" id="cidade" name="cidade"></select>
```

Função javascript que deveria linkar com a busca. Creio que seja nessa parte que esteja o problema.

```
var req;

// FUNÇÃO PARA BUSCA NOTICIA
function buscarOndeComprar() {

// Verificando Browser
if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
   req = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
   req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

// Arquivo PHP juntamente com o valor digitado no campo (método GET)
var estado = document.getElementById('estado').value;
var cidade = document.getElementById('cidade').value;

var url = "busca-onde-comprar.php?estado="+estado+"&cidade="+cidade;

// Chamada do método open para processar a requisição
req.open("Get", url, true);

// Quando o objeto recebe o retorno, chamamos a seguinte função;
req.onreadystatechange = function() {

    // Exibe a mensagem "Buscando Distribuidores e Revendedores..." enquanto carrega
    if(req.readyState == 1) {
        document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = 'Buscando Distribuidores e Revendedores...';
    }

    // Verifica se o Ajax realizou todas as operações corretamente
    if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {

    // Resposta retornada pelo busca.php
    var resposta = req.responseText;

    // Abaixo colocamos a(s) resposta(s) na div resultado
    document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = resposta;
    }
}
req.send(null);
}
```

PÁGINA DA BUSCA:

```
<?php
// Incluir aquivo de conexão
include("bd.php");

// Recebe o valor enviado
$estado = $_GET['estado'];
$cidade = $_GET['cidade'];

// Procura titulos no banco relacionados ao valor
if(!empty($cidade)){
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM distribuidor WHERE estado = ".$estado." and cidade = ".$cidade."");
}else {
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM distribuidor WHERE estado = ".$estado."");
}
// Exibe todos os valores encontrados
if (!empty($sql)){
while ($ondecomprar = mysql_fetch_object($sql)) {
?>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 onde-comprar">
         <h4 class=""><?php echo $ondecomprar->nome?></h4>
         <p><?php echo $ondecomprar->endereco?>, <?php echo $ondecomprar->numero?> - <?php echo $ondecomprar->bairro?><p>
         <p><strong>Cidade:</strong> <?php echo $ondecomprar->cidade?> - <?php echo $ondecomprar->estado?></p>
         <p><strong>Telefone:</strong> <?php echo $ondecomprar->telefone?></p>
         <p><strong>Celular:</strong> <?php echo $ondecomprar->celular?> <i class="fa fa-whatsapp" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php}
} else{
?>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 titulos text-center">
         <h4>Ainda não possuímos nenhum distribuidor ou revendedor cadastrado para este estado.</h4>

    </div>
</div>
<?php

}
?>
```

Exemplo de um site onde tem essa busca:
https://tulipia.com.br/onde-encontrar

Comment: por que não faz assim, a medida que seleciona a cidade ele completa o Estado e os fornecedores

Comment: Pra eu selecionar uma cidade, primeiro eu tenho q escolher o estado, pq para aparecer as cidades eu dependo de um estado selecionado.

Comment: pelo que vi você faz a busca no banco de dados né, da para fazer uma função que a medida que selecione algo ele complete os fornecedores

Comment: Você não prefere usar o AJAX com JQuery?

Comment: Sim, mas como fazer? Estou esbarrando é na execução

Comment: Vou exemplificar a partir dos seus dados.

Comment: @Andrei Coelho aguardo seu exemplo, pra ver se me ajuda a resolver o problema. Obrigado

Comment: Farei hoje a tarde.. usarei exatamente seus parâmetros

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que você precisa fazer é alterar duas coisas...

**1) Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#estado").change(function(){
        buscarOndeComprar();
    });

    $("#cidade").change(function(){
        buscarOndeComprar();
    });

// FUNÇÃO PARA BUSCA DISTRIBUIDORES
function buscarOndeComprar() {

// Verificando Browser
if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
   req = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
   req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
.... resto do código ...
```

**2) O select**

```
<select class="select-onde-comprar" id="estado" name="estado"></select>
<select class="select-onde-comprar" id="estado" name="estado"></select>
```

O problema era que você estava misturando o JQUERY com JS puro. Então o seu select não conseguia chamar a função `buscarOndeComprar()` diretamente.

Comment: Pelo que eu estou vendo o problema está na chamada do arquivo JS. Alterei o JS para apenas isso aqui: function buscarOndeComprar() {
 
  alert("NÃO FOI POSSÍVEL REALIZAR A REQUISIÇÃO");
 } pra ver se aparecia o alerta ao escolher uma opção no select e nem isso acontece. Parece que isso aqui "onchange="buscarOndeComprar()"" não ta chamando a função

Comment: @FredericoMoreira apareceu o alert?

Comment: Não apareceu...por isso estou achando estranho.

Comment: @FredericoMoreira se não apareceu, tente mudar o posicionamento do script

Comment: Primeiro coloque o HTML depois o JAVASCRIPT

Comment: Já esta assim, primeiro HTML, o JS sempre coloco no fim da página.

Comment: @FredericoMoreira Coloque assim `onchange="buscarOndeComprar();"` no select (coloquei um ";")

Comment: Continua não chamando. Veja o link de onde o codigo esta: http://adeliamendonca.com.br/onde-comprar.php Talvez assim fique mais facil de achar o erro

Comment: @FredericoMoreira O problema é que você está misturando as duas coisas... A chamada inicial está dentro do JQuery. Eu vou editar a resposta.

Comment: Eu já mudei várias vezes o lugar da chamada, pra ver se em algum lugar funciona..rsrs

Comment: Acho que descobri o problema. Acho que está causando conflito entre o JS que gera os nomes dos estados e cidades com o JS que faz a busca. Criei um select do zero e chamei o JS e apareceu o alerta.

Comment: @FredericoMoreira alterei a resposta... agora suas funções irão funcionar

Comment: Acho que agora vai..rsrsr. Pelo menos ja gerou um erro no arquivo que faz a busca ao selecionar a cidade...

Comment: @FredericoMoreira não esquece de avaliar a resposta. Abraço!

Comment: Pode deixar que vou avaliar sim. Muito obrigado pela sua ajuda.

Comment: @FredericoMoreira tranquilo... Se precisar chama aqui!

Answer (score 3):

Antes que mais, falta te o "&" que é usado quando se passa mais que um parâmetro no get.

var url = "busca-onde-comprar.php?estado="+estado+"&cidade="+cidade;

Comment: Verdade. Talvez isso solucione.

Comment: Realmente tinha esquecido do &, mas mesmo assim não funcionou. Não faz a busca, não gera erro nem nada..rsrs

Answer (score 0):

Um exemplo simples (mais ou menos) que poderá te ajudar:

**Javascript(jQuery):** - Aqui você fará a requisição ajax e verificará qual estado está selecionado, com o retorno do ajax (que terá um json de cidades no retorno), serão abertas options no select das cidades.

```
$(document).ready( function ()
{
    $("#filtro").change(function() {
        var option = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
        if(option == 0)
            $('#cidade').val("0");
        else
            carregaCidades(option, "#cidade");
    });
    // -- Edit --
    $(document).on("change", "#cidade", function() {
        var option = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
        carregaFornecedores(option, "#cidade"); // Só crie a função e o ajax
    });
  });

function carregaCidades(estado, selecionado="#cidade"){
// alert(selecionado);
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',    
        dataType: 'json',
        data: "op=buscaCidade&estado="+estado,
        url: "buscacidades.php",
        success: function(dados){
            // alert(dados);
            $(selecionado).find('option').remove().end();
            $(selecionado).append($('<option>', {
                value: 0,
                text: 'Todas'
            }));
            for(var i=0;dados.length>i;i++){
                $(selecionado).append($('<option>', {
                    value: dados[i].id_cidade,
                    text: dados[i].nome
                }));
            }

        }, error:function(dados){ alert("ERROU"); }
    });
}
```

**HTML ou View**: - Aqui é a pagina de visualização simples com os ids nos selects que serão usados no jQuery

```
<div>
    <label>Estados</label>
    <select class="c-select" style="line-height: 17px;width:100%" name="filtro" id="filtro">
        <option value="0">Todos os Estados</option>
        <option value="AC">Acre</option>
        <option value="AL">Alagoas</option>
        <option value="AP">Amapá</option>
        <option value="AM">Amazonas</option>
        <option value="BA">Bahia</option>
        <option value="CE">Ceará</option>
        <option value="DF">Distrito Federal</option>
        <option value="ES">Espirito Santo</option>
        <option value="GO">Goiás</option>
        <option value="MA">Maranhão</option>
        <option value="MS">Mato Grosso do Sul</option>
        <option value="MT">Mato Grosso</option>
        <option value="MG">Minas Gerais</option>
        <option value="PA">Pará</option>
        <option value="PB">Paraíba</option>
        <option value="PR">Paraná</option>
        <option value="PE">Pernambuco</option>
        <option value="PI">Piauí</option>
        <option value="RJ">Rio de Janeiro</option>
        <option value="RN">Rio Grande do Norte</option>
        <option value="RS">Rio Grande do Sul</option>
        <option value="RO">Rondônia</option>
        <option value="RR">Roraima</option>
        <option value="SC">Santa Catarina</option>
        <option value="SP">São Paulo</option>
        <option value="SE">Sergipe</option>
        <option value="TO">Tocantins</option>
    </select>
    <label>Cidades</label>
    <select type="text" id="cidade" class="form-control " name="cidade">
        <option value="0">Todas</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**PHP:** - Aqui você só terá que buscar e retornar os valores de acordo com o id selecionado lá no html.

```
$query = "SELECT * from cidades WHERE estado = ".$_POST["estado"];
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo json_encode(mysql_fetch_row($result));
//Teste esse retorno, não tenho certeza da função correta do mysqli
```

Comment: Os select de estado e cidade eu já consegui fazer funcionar. Ao selecionar o estado ele ja preenche o select com as cidades daquele estado. O problema está na hora de fazer uma busca de distribuidores daquele estado e cidade. Não é gerada consulta ao selecionar.

Comment: Por esse campo de cidade ser um campo dinamico teu js vai ter que ser um pouco dferente, vou editar a seção do jQuery

Comment: Eu ja tenho o JS que faz popular os select de estado e cidade, estes estão funcionando perfeitamente. O que preciso fazer é que ao selecionar um determinado estado ele chame uma função js pra fazer a busca no BD sem dar refresh na pagina, aí caso a pessoa escolha uma cidade ai vai fazer outra busca refinando os resultados apenas para aquela cidade. O que esta acontencendo atualmente é q quando seleciono um estado ou cidade não acontece nd, parece que não esta chamando a função JS